# NullPointerException with mockito 2

Tags: java, testing, mockito

I get `java.lang.NullPointerException` with this following code:

```
@Mock
SomeClass retObj;

when(obj.getXXXX(anyString())).thenReturn(retObj);
// obj.getXXXX(null) shows null in other methods
```

It used to work fine in Mockito 1.

Comment: Did you specify ```@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)``` on top of your test class or did you initialize in a *before* mocks with ```MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);```?

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the issue.

Comment: Do you initialize your mocks in `@Before` using `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks`?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it. It turns out Mockito 2.0 handles `null` differently.
When you setup mock as

```
when(obj.getXXXX(anyString())).thenReturn(retObj);
```

But actually the call is `obj.getXXXX(null)` it does not return `retObj`.
Instead it returns `null`.
Hope this helps.